# Subject body added twice when composing a new Hotmail email via hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, hotmail, webmail

I was trying to open Hotmail (Microsoft Live Mail) and compose a new email via a hyperlink in the web page as following:

```
<a href="https://mail.live.com/default.aspx?rru=compose&to=email1@mytest.com&cc=email2@mytest.com&Subject=This is a test&Body=This%20is%20a%20test" target="_blank">Hotmail</a>
```

It opened Hotmail and a new email upon logging in as expected. However, the subject and body that I pre-defined were added twice, as following:

Subject: *This is a test,This is a test*

Body: *This is a test,This is a test*

Is it a bug of Hotmail? or something is missing in the query string?

BTW, other email clients, such as Yahoo! Mail and Gmail have no such problems.

Thanks in advance for any helps or hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a look and tried it. I got the same result. However I managed to fix it using a lower case 's' in Subject:

https://mail.live.com/default.aspx?rru=compose&to=email1@mytest.com&cc=email2@mytest.com&subject=This%20is%20a%20test&body=This%20is%20a%20test

If you notice, the same goes for Body, this should be body

Comment: That works. good trick! Thanks, Ricky. I thought URL always case-insensitive. but i was wrong.